# #WatsonStudio and #Biopython and #fasta file saved on #S3 #Objectstorage

Tags: amazon-s3, biopython, fasta, object-storage, data-science-experience

I need to read a fasta file uploaded on Cloud Object storage using Biopython.
I've anotebook in Python 2.7 in Watson Studio.
Does anyone have tried this?

Comment: Usually you want to explore some options out and see why they are failing before posting question. Hope below answer helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Download the sample dataset from biopython :- http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc49

Drag and drop the file to Cloud Object Storage.

Click Down arrow next to that file and click InsertStreamingBody object

[image]

This will insert a streamingBody object(ex. streaming_body_1), Please run that cell.

Next read that in a bytes Object

```
fastareadbytes = streaming_body_1.read()
```

Now we need to decode the bytes to string and then convert it to StringIO so that we can use it in SeqIO.parse() to read it

```
from io import StringIO
from Bio import SeqIO
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(StringIO(fastareadbytes.decode('utf-8')), "fasta"):
    print(seq_record.id)
    print(repr(seq_record.seq))
    print(len(seq_record))
```

You will see response like this:-
[image]